# Linker errors in a basic Apache module

Tags: c, apache, apr

I am attempting to write a "hello world" module for Apache HTTPD 2.4. I'm receiving some linker errors when building the module, and many Google searches have not revealed a solution.

My questions are:

1. How can I resolve the ap_hook_handler linker error? I've searched through the Apache Portable Runtime source and headers and have not found it.
2. Why is there an undefined reference to main? I thought shared objects don't have a main() entry point.

The source code:

```
// Dependancies: apr-devel apr-util-devel

#include <httpd.h>
#include <http_config.h>
#include <apr_hooks.h>

static int test_handler(request_rec* request)
{
        return OK;
}

static void register_hooks(apr_pool_t *pool)
{
        ap_hook_handler(test_handler, NULL, NULL, APR_HOOK_LAST);
}

module AP_MODULE_DECLARE_DATA test_module =
{
        STANDARD20_MODULE_STUFF,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        register_hooks
};
```

The build command:

```
apxs -lapr-1 -laprutil-1 -c test.c -o mod_test.so
```

The errors:

```
apxs -lapr-1 -laprutil-1 -c test.c -o mod_test.so
/usr/lib64/apr-1/build/libtool --silent --mode=compile gcc -prefer-pic -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing  -DLINUX=2 -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -pthread -I/usr/include/httpd  -I/usr/include/apr-1   -I/usr/include/apr-1   -c -o test.lo test.c && touch test.slo
/usr/lib64/apr-1/build/libtool --silent --mode=link gcc -o test.la  -lapr-1 -laprutil-1 -rpath /usr/lib64/httpd/modules -module -avoid-version    test.lo -o mod_test.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
.libs/test.o: In function `register_hooks':
/root/test/test.c:14: undefined reference to `ap_hook_handler'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=65536
```

Comment: I don't know `apxs`, but when using `gcc` one has to give the `-shared` parameter to build a shared library. This parameter is not listed in the debug output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order matters and the filenames have to go last:

```
apxs -c -o mod_test.so test.c
```

To install it automatically:

```
apxs -i -c -o mod_test.so -c test.c
```

This should work

Answer (score 1):

As Ctx said, the order of parameters really matters. I use the following format of the APXS:

```
$APACHE/bin/apxs -c -a -i mod_test.c
```

what compiles, adds and installs the test module. It produces this output:

```
/usr/local/apr/build-1/libtool --silent --mode=compile gcc -prefer-pic   -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -g -O2 -pthread -I$APACHE_HOME/include  -I/usr/local/apr/include/apr-1   -I/usr/local/apr/include/apr-1   -c -o mod_test.lo mod_test.c && touch mod_test.slo
/usr/local/apr/build-1/libtool --silent --mode=link gcc    -o mod_test.la  -rpath $APACHE_HOME/modules -module -avoid-version mod_test.lo
ar: `u' modifier ignored since `D' is the default (see `U')
$APACHE_HOME/build/instdso.sh SH_LIBTOOL='/usr/local/apr/build-1/libtool' mod_test.la $APACHE_HOME/modules
/usr/local/apr/build-1/libtool --mode=install install mod_test.la $APACHE_HOME/modules/
libtool: install: install .libs/mod_test.so $APACHE_HOME/modules/mod_test.so
libtool: install: install .libs/mod_test.lai $APACHE_HOME/modules/mod_test.la
libtool: install: install .libs/mod_test.a $APACHE_HOME/modules/mod_test.a
libtool: install: chmod 644 $APACHE_HOME/modules/mod_test.a
libtool: install: ranlib $APACHE_HOME/modules/mod_test.a
libtool: finish: 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Libraries have been installed in:
   $APACHE_HOME/modules

If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
specify the full pathname of the library, or use the `-LLIBDIR'
flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
     during execution
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
     during linking
   - use the `-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
   - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to `/etc/ld.so.conf'

See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
chmod 755 $APACHE_HOME/modules/mod_test.so
[activating module `test' in $APACHE_HOME/conf/httpd.conf]
```

By providing the **-o** option you can get rid of **undefined reference to main** error message.